# AWS cli filter not applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, security-groups

I want to receive some values from an AWS `SecurityGroup` and am using the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $GROUP \
  --filters 'Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=22 Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=22' \
  --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions[*].{cidr:Ipv6Ranges[*].CidrIpv6,from:FromPort,to:ToPort}' \
  --output json
```

The output however delivers all existing port ranges whereas only port 22 is expected:

```
[
    [
        {
            "cidr": [
                "::/0"
            ],
            "from": 80,
            "to": 80
        },
        {
            "cidr": [
                "2001::snip/128"
            ],
            "from": 22,
            "to": 22
        },
        {
            "cidr": [
                "::/0"
            ],
            "from": 443,
            "to": 443
        }
    ]
]
```

It seems my filter isn't applied. Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter is working correctly.  You've requested all security groups that contain (but are not limited to) ToPort == 22 and FromPort == 22.  Your query needs to limit what is output.  You can do this by adding:

```
?ToPort == `22`
```

to the IpPermissions[] part of the query to further limit the output.

The following should give you the output you're looking for:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters 'Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=22 Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=22'   --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions[?ToPort == `22`].{cidr:Ipv6Ranges[*].CidrIpv6,from:FromPort,to:ToPort}' --output json
```

**References**

[CLI Usage Output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)

Comment: I should have read that page more carefully. Many thanks!